# Linux LS -T output in Find command

Tags: linux, unix, duplicates, find, ls

I have prepared a script with ls -t to fetch latest file and compare with duplicates i use below

`ls -t *xml |awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}'`

However for large size folder ls command not working. so i tried with

```
find ./ -type f \( -iname "*.xml" \) | sort |awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}'
```

but newly created files is not extracted first so i am unable to retain newly created file.

i need to change find command in similiar way output of ls -t command.

Comment: One of the reasons for Stackoverflow's success is its strict adherence to a standard format.  In the standard format, to mark a question as solved, one accepts the best answer (look for the green checkmark).  For more on SO's peculiar-seeming customs, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

If your files are guaranteed not to have newlines in their names, try:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -rg | sed -E 's/[^ ]* //' | awk -F_ '{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}'
```

For a more robust solution that accepts all filenames, try (GNU tools required):

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -rgz | sed -Ez 's/[^ ]* //' | awk -v RS="\0" -F_ '{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}'
```

#### How it works

So that we have an example, let's create three files:

```
$ touch b_1
$ touch b_2
$ touch b_3
```

We use `find` to print out the file's timestamp followed by the file's name:

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'
1511234577.7454717760 ./b_3
1511234574.9814419470 ./b_1
1511234576.1054540780 ./b_2
```

We want the files sorted by timestamp, newest file first, so we use `sort -rg` to do a numeric reverse sort on the timestamp (expressed as seconds since epoch):

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -rg
1511234577.7454717760 ./b_3
1511234576.1054540780 ./b_2
1511234574.9814419470 ./b_1
```

The next step is to get rid of the timestamps.  So, we use sed:

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -rg | sed -E 's/[^ ]* //'
./b_3
./b_2
./b_1
```

Now, we can use your awk script to identify the older files:

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -rg | sed -E 's/[^ ]* //' | awk -F_ '{if (++dup[$1] >= 2) print}'
./b_2
./b_1
```

#### Compatibility

Very old GNU systems don't support the `-E` option to sed.  On such systems, one may replace `-E` with `-r` like:

```
sed -r 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Or, for the more robust version:

```
sed -rz 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Comment: Thanks but sed command not working for me. sed: invalid option -- E

Comment: @misterbean2 Are you on an old RedHat system?  Replace `-E` with `-r` like `sed -r 's/[^ ]* //'` or, for the more robust version `sed -rz 's/[^ ]* //'`

Comment: sed -r works perfect with same parameter. Thanks alot

Comment: @misterbean2 I am curious: what linux distribution/version are you using?